If any direct product of the regular module is a submodule of a projective module, then is any direct product of the regular module projective?
Let $R$ be a ring with unity.
As is well known, $R$ is left perfect and right coherent if and only if any product of projective left modules is projective. If $M$ is a left torsionless module over $R$, then $M$ is a submodule of $R^I$ for some index set $I$ by the definition of a torsionless module. If $R$ is a left perfect and right coherent ring, then $R^I$ is projective. Therefore, a left module $M$ is torsionless over a left perfect and right coherent ring if and only if $M$ is a submodule of a projective module.
Now the question arises:
If any left torsionless module over a ring $R$ is a submodule of a projective module, can we conclude that $R$ is left perfect and right coherent?
Because any left torsionless module over a ring $R$ is a submodule of a projective module if and only if $R^I$ is a submodule of some projective module for any index set $I$, and $R$ is left perfect and right coherent if and only if $R^I$ is projective for any index set $I$, as stated in Theorem 3.3 on page 467 of the paper DIRECT PRODUCTS OF MODULES.
So the above question changes to: if $R^I$ is a submodule of some projective module for any index set $I$, can we conclude that $R^I$ is projective for any index set $I$? In other words, if any direct product of the regular module is a submodule of a projective module, then is any direct product of the regular module projective?

This is actually equivalent to the following statement: If any direct product of projective modules is a submodule of a projective module, can we then conclude that any direct product of projective modules is projective?
